# Efficiently requesting multiple entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I need to request lists of different entities without a relation (in order to create that relation). Example:

```
var attributeGroups = db.Attribute_Group.Where(g => attributeGroupIds.Contains(g.Id));
var attributes = db.Attribute.Where(g => attributeIds.Contains(g.Id));
```

When I iterate the results later, will it make multiple database calls? Is there a way to only make 1?

Comment: Append `.ToList()` or `.ToArray()`.

Comment: That will still result in 2 round trips to the database. I was wondering if I can get it down to 1.

Comment: How much do your calls take? Do you really need that optimization (If any)?

Comment: Your tables are not related so there is no way you can get them in one call. maybe you need to redesign your DB if there's a need for one

Comment: I simplified the example, but there are more tables I'm hitting than just these 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your only option is calling stored procedure which return multiple resultsets. see http://romiller.com/2012/08/15/code-first-stored-procedures-with-multiple-results/